# What is the function declaration for the Java finalize method?

Tags: java, declaration, finalize

I've been searching code for the finalize for nearly 1 mon. Can u pls help me for the code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close your question because it isn't posed clearly enough to garner any answers.  Please edit your question and elaborate on what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question because I searched for the code contained in both answers on the site, and this question was the first result.  I recreated the subject line to match what the answers clearly felt was the question.  Also, +1.

Answer (score 2):

[finalize](http://www.janeg.ca/scjp/gc/finalize.html)

```
protected void finalize() throws Throwable
{
    try
    {
        //close unmanaged resources
    } finally {
        super.finalize();
    }
}
```

Note that outside of unmanaged resources, you shouldn't ever be doing this..

Comment: +1 I'm currently doing this because I want to see in my log verification that a certain class is being cleaned up.  I suppose that's "outside of unmanaged resources", but I find that phrase a bit obfuscated.  Maybe it's the hidden double negative.  Maybe it's that I would never use anything big enough to be tarred with the epithet "Resource Management".

Answer (score 2):

```
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    try {
        close();        // close open files
    } finally {
        super.finalize();
    }
}
```

You call super.finalize() in the finally block.

[Source](http://www.janeg.ca/scjp/gc/finalize.html)

Comment: Looks like we both googled the same link - find it hard to believe that a month's worth of googling wouldn't start with [this](http://www.google.com/search?q=java+finalize)

Comment: My first search brought me right here.  I remembered the proper declaration for this method throwing something, and wanted to see it.  Of course, I did my first search on SO.